# Liferay DynamicQuery - xPath and Array comparison

Tags: sql, xpath, liferay, liferay-6, dynamicquery

My final goal is I want to get plid and portletId that can be display my article(or entry with any type if it is possible).

I have sql query that return me any portlet availble for display my article.
But when I have to use dynamicQuery to get the same results, I get problem with xPath and array comparison, please help!

```
SELECT * FROM portletpreferences pr
WHERE pr.preferences != '<portlet-preferences />' AND pr.ownerid = 0 AND pr.portletid ilike '%_INSTANCE_%' AND pr.plid IN(
    SELECT layout.plid FROM layout 
          WHERE layout.type_ = 'portlet' AND layout.groupid = 19 AND layout.hidden_ is false)
AND pr.portletpreferencesid IN (
        SELECT pr.portletpreferencesid FROM portletpreferences pr
          WHERE 'true' = ANY(xpath('//preference[name="anyAssetType"]/value/text()', XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT pr.preferences))::text[])
               OR (SELECT (array(SELECT id_ FROM journalstructure))::text[]) &&  xpath('//preference[name="classTypeIds"]/value/text()', XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT pr.preferences))::text[] )
```

Comment: Why do you use queries and not the APIs and services that Liferay provides?

Comment: :-? i dont know, when create new display type for assetpublisher on liferay portal, I just copy existed file and edit the code, it always include many file I needed, however, when do that, i only can use liferay API and services

Comment: To add a new asset publisher display style you should be able to use this: http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Asset+Publisher+Portlet. You just need 1 JSP file and a property file change. I don't quite understand why you would need to do a DynamicQuery to achieve a new display style?

Comment: I want to open my content in another page and portlet, so I need to custom viewURL, using dynamicQuery to find out which page(plid and portletId) can be display my content

Comment: If you just want to show the content on another page you could maybe use the 'Display Page' option of the Asset Publisher: http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/lp-6-1-ugen03-using-the-asset-publisher-portlet-0

Comment: hmm, I dont want to give end user permission to choose which pages his content will display, It must be automatically. In my case, i had changed my alg, use dynamicQuery to find out which pages  - and - assetpublisher have a same title with structure name, or at least any asset publisher with a same title with it. However, thanks for reply

Comment: The configuration of these settings are only for users with enough permissions and usually you wouldn't give end users these kinds of permissions, only administrators.

Answer (score 0):

If you are bent upon using this same query, then use this query directly with `Custom-SQL` in liferay by creating custom-finders instead of using `DynamicQuery`. That would give you a lot of flexibility in using any type of SQL query directly.

I don't think this query can be converted to `DynamicQuery`, but if you do manage to convert it then please do post it here :-)

Answer (score 0):

DynamicQuery is very powerful, see e.g. my answer how to find layouts with specific JournalArticles. I think your requirement is similar to this one: 
[Liferay: How to find all Layouts with the specific JournalArticle in AssetPublisher portlets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986218/liferay-how-to-find-all-layouts-with-the-specific-journalarticle-in-assetpublis/12038652#12038652)